# Como criar todas combinações possíveis a partir de uma string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tentei usar

```py
a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
itertools.product(a, repeat=4)
```

para criar todas palavras possiveis com 4 letras, porém me parece que quando a quantidade é muito grande ele não funciona corretamente.

Existe alguma alternativa para lidar com combinações altas?

A unica solução que eu pensei até agora é usar random.choice para criar uma palavra aleatoria e usar um filtro para não escolher palavras repetidas

Comment: Qual o erro? A função aparenta funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: Aparentemente você viu que o `product` não retornava uma lista e assumiu que "deu probledúsma por que é muito grande". Dica para conseguir fazer coisas legais em programação: tente e experimente. Se você desconfiuou que o problema era "nossa , isso é muita coisa", deveria ter tentado com um conjunto menor de dados pra ver se funcionava. Aí ia detectar que esse não era o problema.

Comment: -1 : A pergunta é ruim, "Não funciona corretamente" é muito vago. Se [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/370932/edit) e elaborar melhor a pergunta (de preferência com exemplos do problema encontrado) retiro meu voto negativo.

Comment: Descobri que o problema estava na IDE,ela não conseguia mostrar a lista completa, por isso que quando eu digitava uma palavra aleatoria não aparecia

Answer (score 4):

Você está fazendo alguma outra coisa errada - apesar do número de combinações ser grande, no meu sistema, o itertools.product gerou as mais de 400.000 combinações possíveis nesse caso em menos de 0.1 segundo.

O que você chama de "não funcionar corretamente"? Lembre-se que o itertools devolve uma tupla com as 4 letras, você tem que fazer alguma outra chamada para juntar as letras em uma palavra:

```
In [73]: c = [''.join(b)  for b in itertools.product(a, repeat=4)]

In [74]: len(c)
Out[74]: 456976

In [76]: print(c[0:50])
['aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', 'aaad', 'aaae', 'aaaf', 'aaag', 'aaah', 'aaai', 'aaaj', 'aaak', 'aaal', 'aaam', 'aaan', 'aaao', 'aaap', 'aaaq', 'aaar', 'aaas', 'aaat', 'aaau', 'aaav', 'aaaw', 'aaax', 'aaay', 'aaaz', 'aaba', 'aabb', 'aabc', 'aabd', 'aabe', 'aabf', 'aabg', 'aabh', 'aabi', 'aabj', 'aabk', 'aabl', 'aabm', 'aabn', 'aabo', 'aabp', 'aabq', 'aabr', 'aabs', 'aabt', 'aabu', 'aabv', 'aabw', 'aabx']
```

Comment: deveria ter todas combinações possiveis de 4 letras certo?, porém quando eu vou testar uma palavra de 4 letras aleatorias, muitas delas não aparecem

Comment: tem todas. Como você está testando?
O operador "in" pode dizer se uma palavra está presente aí ou não.

Comment: descobri que o problema estava na IDE

Answer (score 2):

A função `product` de `itertools` retorna um *objeto iterável*. Assim, para acessar, você precisa passar por uma iteração com laço `for`, por exemplo. Veja:

```
import string
import itertools

abc  = string.ascii_lowercase
prod = itertools.product(abc, repeat=4)

for i in prod:
    print(i)
```

O resultado (*output*) pode ser visto [neste arquivo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jfcandidofilho/stackoverflow/10357ca6fd6d4df9cfab689681a467a264b8f1b3/370932/output.txt).